# sytemctl --user start results in "Failed to connect to bus: no such file or directory"

Tags: server, systemd

I'm on an Ubuntu server (16.04, via SSH), trying to set up a service to check mail, and following these instructions: https://bostonenginerd.com/posts/notmuch-of-a-mail-setup-part-1-mbsync-msmtp-and-systemd/.

When I enter:

```
systemctl --user start checkmail.timer
```

I get:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I'm lost as to why. I followed the exact same instructions on a desktop and had no issues.

Any suggestions on how to resolve?